# readfile() does not work with some URLs

Tags: php, url, readfile

The following code does not get me the correct file:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
readfile("http://player.vimeo.com/play_redirect?clip_id=24195442&sig=49daac0ff885745c27601a80402bba14&time=1351783454&quality=hd&codecs=H264&type=moogaloop_local&embed_location=");
?>
```

Instead, it seems to download http://player.vimeo.com/play_redirect?clip_id=24195442.
I have tried using *htmlentities* or *htmlspecialchars* but it does not change anything.

Comment: I haven't taken much time to look at this, but are you sure that vimeo isn't doing some neato validation that you are not a proxy (which you are in this case). I used to run a site, and people were using my service to proxy our images and videos, so I added checks (using cookies) to make sure they couldn't do this... vimeo likely has much better ways of preventing you from doing that type of content stealing.

Comment: The URL http://player.vimeo.com/play_redirect?clip_id=24195442&sig=49daac0ff885745c27601a80402bba14&time=1351783454&quality=hd&codecs=H264&type=moogaloop_local&embed_location= also returns Permission denied .. why are you expecting another result ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common thing on video and download sites. To prevent trivial direct linking or hot-linking, they generate a unique URL for the main data after user interaction with the page, video player, or a CAPTCHA. That's what the `sig` and `time` sections of your URL are. Generated URLs of this sort are usually tied to the user by IP address and will expire after a time.

To pass-through that type of content, you have to decipher the steps used to generate the video URL. It's often as easy as requesting the HTML page then looking for the URL in the Flash applet parameters or a script tag. Other sites generate the URL inside a complex client-side script or Flash applet.

I took a quick look at Vimeo and figured out how to get the URL and it seems to be working okay. Try this:

```
$clipId = 24195442;

ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:10.0.9) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.9');
$config = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://player.vimeo.com/config/' . $clipId));
$videoUrl = 'http://player.vimeo.com/play_redirect?clip_id=' . $clipId .
    '&sig=' . $config->request->signature .
    '&time=' . $config->request->timestamp;
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
readfile($videoUrl);
```

Yes you do have to set the [User-Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string. Vimeo rejected it when it didn't look like a real browser.

I don't know if there's a Vimeo API which says that that's *supposed* to work. Be warned that it might only work so long as Vimeo doesn't change their site structure. The most reliable thing to do is to save or cache the video file and serve it locally from your own server, if you possibly can.

Answer (score 0):

Try this exmaple, is based on the Vimeo Simple API (version 2). Just copy&paste to try it yourself...

http://www.lib.montana.edu/~jason/files/api/vimeo/item.txt

Check that there're lines commented for use the curl_init() method if needed. 
Starts on line 57 and final on 69. But ignore it if example runs on the first time.